# Symfony 4 - I have to use circular references services

Tags: symfony, service, reference, containers, circular-dependency

I have two services: **AbsenceService** and **ValidationService**.

I just added a feature to my project and therefore, I need to use a function of my **ValidationService** from the **AbsenceService**.

But my **ValidationService** already has a reference to **AbsenceService**.

So I can not use my **ValidationService** with my **AbsenceService**

```php
// AbsenceService.php

    private $validationService;

    public function __construct(..., ValidationService $validationService)
        {
            ...
            $this->adminService = $adminService;
        }
```

> Circular reference detected for service "App\Services\AbsenceService", path: "App\Services\AbsenceService -> App\Services\ValidationService -> App\Services\AbsenceService".

How can I use my `ValidationService` in my `AbsenceService` please ?

EDIT:

```
//AbsenceService.php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use DateTime;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Absence;
use App\Repository\AbsenceRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Date;

class AbsenceService
{

    /**
     * Manager
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * Repository des absences
     *
     * @var ObjectRepository
     */
    private $repoAbsences;

    /**
     * Service mail
     *
     * @var MailerService
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * templating
     *
     * @var EngineInterface
     */
    private $templating;

    private $adminService;

    private $validationService;

    public function __construct(EngineInterface $templating, EntityManagerInterface $manager, AbsenceRepository $repoAbsence, MailerService $mailer, AdminService $adminService, ValidationService $validationService)
    {
        $this->templating = $templating;
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->repoAbsences = $repoAbsence;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->adminService = $adminService;
        $this->validationService = $validationService;
    }

    /**
     * Déposer une demande d'absence et renvoie un message flash pour informer l'utilisateur du résultat
     * de sa demande
     * @param Absence $absence
     * @param User $user
     * @return array
     */
    public function poserAbsence(Absence $absence, User $user)
    {
        // some code

        $this->manager->persist($absence);
        $this->manager->persist($user);

        $this->manager->flush();

        // Here, I've to use my Validation service
        /*$bool = $this->validationService->checkAutoValidation($absence);

        if(!$bool)
        {
            $this->sendMail($absence);
        }*/

        // end ValidationService


        if($absence->getEtat() == "En attente")
        {
            $message = "Demande d'absence envoyée !";
        }
        else
        {
            $message = "Absence enregistrée !";
        }

        $flash = $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            $message
        );

        return $flash;
    }
```

And

```
//ValidationService.php
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Entity\Absence;
use App\Entity\UserSearch;
use App\Repository\AbsenceRepository;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use App\Repository\ValidateurRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ValidationService
{

    /**
     * Repository des validations
     *
     * @var ObjectRepository
     */
    private $repoValidateur;

    /**
     * Repository des absences
     *
     * @var ObjectRepository
     */
    private $repoAbsences;

    /**
     * Manager
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * Service absence
     *
     * @var AbsenceService
     */
    private $absenceService;

    /**
     * Service mail
     *
     * @var MailerService
     */
    private $mailer;

    /**
     * Repository des users
     *
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    private $repoUsers;




    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager, ValidateurRepository $repoValidateur, AbsenceRepository $repoAbsences, AbsenceService $absenceService, MailerService $mailer, UserRepository $repoUsers)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
        $this->repoValidateur = $repoValidateur;
        $this->repoAbsences = $repoAbsences;
        $this->absenceService = $absenceService;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->repoUsers = $repoUsers;
    }

//Some code

    /**
     * Vérifie si le prochain validateur a l'auto-validation. Si oui, valider automatiquement l'absence
     *
     * @param Absence $absence
     * @return void
     */
    public function checkAutoValidation(Absence $absence)
    {
        $nextValidateur = $this->getNextValidateur($absence);

        if($nextValidateur->getAutoValidation() == true)
        {
            $this->valider($nextValidateur, $absence);
        }
    }
/**
     * Accorder sa validation à une demande
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Absence $absence
     * @return void
     */
    public function valider(User $user, Absence $absence, $superValidation = false)
    {
        // $ordre = $this->getOrdreValidateur($user, $absence);
        $nextValidateur = $this->getNextValidateur($absence, true);
        $ordre = $nextValidateur->getOrdre();

        $arrayValidation = $absence->getValidation();

        if ($superValidation) {
            if ($this->isSuperValidateurOfAbsenceGroupe($absence, $user)) {

                $arrayValidation = [];
                $absence->setValidation($arrayValidation);
                $absence->setEtat("Validée")
                        ->setSignataire($user);
            }
        } else {

            if (($key = array_search($ordre, $arrayValidation)) !== false) {
                unset($arrayValidation[$key]);
            }

            $absence->setValidation($arrayValidation);

            if (empty($arrayValidation)) {
                $absence->setEtat("Validée")
                        ->setSignataire($user);
            }
            else
            {
                $absence = $this->checkIfCanValidAgain($user, $absence);
                $this->checkAutoValidation($absence);
            }
        }

        $this->manager->persist($absence);
        $this->manager->flush();

        $this->absenceService->sendMail($absence);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of your two services ? including the definition of the 2 `Class` ? I'm sure there is a workaround

Comment: Do you want the entire code of both services? They are huge you know, 600 lines each.

I will update my code with as much info as possible on both services with the functions I need to use

Comment: not everything of course but at least the important information and the interconnected methods

Comment: Here I updated while trying to put what was needed ( Sorry for the bad english, I'm french )

Comment: If you really had to then you could inject the container into AbsenceService and then pull ValidationService from it when you need it.  But there are very very very few legit cases of cross dependency.  Maybe see if you can extract the shared functionality into a third service.  It is also possible that using a [lazy service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) might help.

Comment: In fact I'm going to need a function from my ValidationService, but it may have to use a lot of other functions of the same service in some cases to do some processing. The lazy service could still work?

Comment: I think that you need to rethink the organization of you're services and trie to better split functions, lazy services won't protect you against circular references.
be carreful `checkAutoValidation`doesn't return a `bool`

Comment: Yet they are very well split. My ```AbsenceService``` is used to manage the creation of my absences. And the```ValidationService``` is used to manage everything related to the validation of absences.
At the limit, as Cerad said, I could create a service that would serve as an intermediary.

```AbsenceService``` would call ```ThirdService``` to call the desired ```ValidationService``` function?

Comment: And yes, well seen for the last comment of your answer

Comment: Your code does seem a bit convoluted and pay attention to what was already said about checkAutoValidation.  It appears that your ValidationService has $this->absenceService->sendMail($absence);  Doubtful that the validation service itself should be responsible for triggering an email.  And updating a database as part of a validation process?  That seems a bit bizarre.